# running bat by jar makes files appear a wrong place

Tags: java, batch-file

i'm making a program so it's easier to manage my game servers for me and my friends, but when i make my program start the server by jar some of the game files appear a wrong place (not where the server it self are, is there any way to change that?

i use ProcessBuilder to start a bat file that starts a .jar in the same folder.

```
    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("Minecraft-server.bat"); //it gets the full path in the .bat with %~dp0
    builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
    builder.redirectInput();
    Process process = builder.start();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you should be specifying the full path to the `bat` file, and you can use [`ProcessBuilder.directory(File)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#directory%28java.io.File%29) to set *this process builder's working directory. Subprocesses subsequently started by this object's [`start()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#start()) method will use this as their working directory.*

```
String batFile = "Minecraft-server.bat";
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(batFile);
builder.directory(new File(batFile).getParentFile());
```